# Who tells me this reaction?

Tags: linear-algebra, chemistry

$$P_4O_{10} + H_2O\rightarrow H_3PO_4$$ I've a solution what I couldn't sense. How did we find this matrix and vectors? as you can see:
 $$\begin{bmatrix}
        4 & 1 & 0 \\
        10 & 4 & 1 \\
        0 & 3 & 2 \\ 
        \end{bmatrix}$$
If someone tells me how did we find vector of a reaction?

Comment: I have no idea why someone would use matrices to balance such simple reaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to balance the equation between its constitutive elements.

You are searching $x,y,z$ such that $x\ P_4O_{10}+y\ H_2O\to z\ H_3PO_4$

$\begin{cases} 
\text{balancing P}:4x=z\\ 
\text{balancing O}:10x+y=4z\\
\text{balancing H}:2y=3z
\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases} 
4x+0y=1z\\ 
10x+1y=4z\\
0x+2y=3z
\end{cases}\iff\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 0 \\ 10 & 1 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 4 \\ 3\end{pmatrix} z$

But you could as well express it like this, putting $z$ on left side with a minus sign.

$\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 0 & -1 \\ 10 & 1 & -4 \\ 0 & 2 & -3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}=0$

Now look at this presentation to see how it is built $\begin{vmatrix}
P_4 & P_0 &\to & P_1\\ 
O_{10} & O_1&\to & O_4\\ 
H_0 & H_2 &\to &H_3
\end{vmatrix}$

This matrix presentation is generally useful for equations with many products involved, although with simple reactions like this one, it is generally manageable by hand from the first system :

$\begin{cases} 4x=z\\ 10x+y=4z\\ 2y=3z \end{cases}\iff
\begin{cases} z=4x\\ 10x+6x=16x\\ y=6x \end{cases}\iff
\begin{cases} z=4x\\ y=6x \end{cases}$

Since $x,y,z$ are integer in chemical reactions, $x=1,y=6,z=4$ works well.

$P_4O_{10}+6\,H_2O\to 4\,H_3PO_4$

Comment: your answer is great what I'm looking for. Thanks too much!

Comment: Putting all of the species on the “same side” of the equation has the advantage of a useful sanity check: when you’re done, the reactants will have positive coefficients and the products will have negative coefficients.

Comment: can you add how to solve it with using matrix too?

Comment: Well, if you solve the matrix problem manually it leads to solve exactly the same system, so I guess this alternative method is supposed to be solved using a CAS and ask for $\operatorname{eigenvector}(A,0)$ and it should return $(1,6,4)$.

Comment: can you add how to solve it with using matrix(null space)?

Comment: But this is already the null space. We have solved $Av=0$ for the matrix $A$ and the vector $v=(x,y,z)$, eigenvectors for a zero eigenvalue is the definition of null space.

Answer (score 1):

I would write the matrix differently. You have three variables (number of molecules of each of the compounds) and three equations (stating that the numbers of atoms of each *element* must balance). For example, if there are $a$ molecules of $P_4O_{10}$, $b$ molecules of $H_2O$, and $c$ molecules of $H_3PO_4$, saying that the number of phosphorus atoms must balance would be the equation
$4a+0b-c=0$. I would end up with the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 0 & -1 \\ 10 & 1 & -4 \\ 0 & 2 & -3 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: I mean how to find vector of reaction to put it on matrix.

Comment: @Aboubakar you solve for the null space and look for an integer solution. Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I need find vector before finding null space.

Comment: So how to find vector of a reaction?

Comment: I just need learn how to find vector.

Comment: Read what I wrote. The variables are $a$, $b$, and $c$. Those form a vector.

Comment: I couldn't sense it. can you solve it other way?

Comment: Now, I really need how to find vector what I'm looking for method to find null space.

Answer (score 1):

Why do it via a matrix at all: maybe simple number theory can help us. If the three amounts are called $a,b,c$ the amount of $P$'s tells us that $c= 4a$ while looking at the $H$'s we get $2b = 3c$. Then finally the $O$'s tell us that $10a+ b = 4c$,

The gcm of the numbers involved is $\gcd(4,3,2,10) = 60$, so we multiply the equation $10a + b = 4c$ by 6, to make all the coefficients multiples of the gcm and we get $60a + 6b = 24c$, or using the other relations $4a=c, 2b=3c$ we get $15c + 9c = 24c$, which comes out nicely. So $(a,b,c) =(15, 9, 24)$ works but we can reduce that to $(5,3,8)$ dividing by $3$. So we have a (minimal) solution.

Comment: Isn'T matrix method better than this?

Comment: What I described is the usual way to do it, I believe @Aboubakar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer great.